# How can I default the "Append Comments" checkbox to unchecked when creating new order in backend?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, default-values

When a member of our staff creates a new order in the Magento backend, they frequently add comments into the order but forget to uncheck the "Append Comments" checkbox on the order.  Sometimes we don't want the customer to see those comments in the order email, and would prefer to have that checkbox default to unchecked.

How can I change that?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean: [image: uncheck this by default]

Comment: U need to override `magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\totals.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the checkbox is defaulted to checked because the SQL schema for the `quote.customer_note_notify` column is set to a default value of "1". Switching this to "0" will default the checkbox to unchecked.

By navigating the deep rabbit hole called Magento's source code, I came to the conclusion that when you click the "Create New Order" button, Magento literally creates an order record in the DB, even before any useful data is know about the order... That's why flipping the default value alters the behavior, as the blank order page is pulling its default information form a DB record.

I'm not a fan altering Magento's default schema, but this is a pretty straightforward change. Might be a good idea to add a DB migration. You could also look into the process that creates the DB record initially, and see if there's a way to change the `customer_note_notify` before record creation.